# How to find how many cosets are of $H \cap K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm confuse to find how many cosets of $H \cap K$ are in the G?
If $G$ is a group of order 48, then $H$ of order 8, $K$ of order 6, <= $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of elements in a finite group divides the order of the group. So when considering $H\cap K$ then it's elements must divide the order of both $H$ and $K$ so $H\cap K$ has order $2$. so there are $24$ cosets of $H\cap K$. I assumed that all subgroups are proper here.

Comment: But why its cosets 24? Maybe you can give the theorem?

Comment: Recall the theorem of Lagrange that if $H$ is subgroup of $G$ then $|G| = (G:H)|H|$. Try this on $\mathbb{Z}_{48}$. Where our $H\cap K=\{0,24\}$

Comment: I'm sorry for my late comment.
I'll try to undestand step by step.
Then with the theorem we get ($G$ : $H$) = 6, so ($G$ : $K$) = 8, then why $H \cap K$ = {$0$, $24$} ? Sorry for may stupidity Spock, I'm stuck at abstract algebra. Please be patient with me.

Comment: That was a concrete example. if the order of the element must divide the order of the group then 1,2,3 and 6 are possible orders for elements of K. Among these numbers it's only 1 and 2 that divide 8 so except for the trivial group, $H\cap K$  would be a group with 2 elements.

Comment: Okay, I get it why $H \cap K$ is 2 element, now why its element is {$0$, $24$} and how to find the coset of $H \cap K$ step by step, I'm sorry for asking you this.

Comment: when the group has 2 elements then one of them is the identity and the other is an element of order 2 which in the example $\mathbb{Z}_{48}$ is 24. Cosets: $1+\{0,24\}=\{1,25\}$,$2+\{0,24\}=\{2,26\}$,...,$24+\{0,24\}=\{24,0\}$,$25+\{0,24\}=\{25,1\}$. This way you understand why there's 24 of them. try computing cosets for other groups to get more familiar.

Comment: why $25$ + {$25$, $1$} not 25 + {$0$, $24$} ?
Oh, you've corrected it, I'm still learning it now.

Comment: Okay, it means 1 + {$0$, $24$} = 25 + {$0$, $24$}, and so on.
Then because that, there are only 24 cosets which are identically, isn't it? But, how about the right coset ? Or because the right coset = left coset, so only 24 cosets that have meaning, right?

Comment: You're right and yes left and right coset here are equal so 24 distinct cosets. notice that this was only an example for a better illustration.